# SwiftUI fullScreenCover without animations

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

How can I disable animations on `fullScreenCover` ? I want the view to show up directly, not have it slide in from the bottom.

Thanks

Edit: it seems the question got closed because of lack of "debugging details". Seriously?

The above call defaults to a slide in animation, I just want to know how to do it without animations. No idea what "debugging details" are required here ...

Comment: i don't think there is a solution to this however there is maybe a workaround

Comment: Sadly.. curators want to see code. Put an example of the usage and the default behaviour.

Comment: Might help to add some code showing how you use the `fullScreenCover` function, to make sure potential answers are on-topic.