# SwiftUI: show fullScreenCover without animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

[This amazing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65275983/swiftui-fullscreencover-without-animations) got closed due to "lack of technical details", so I'm sure to put a plenty of here.

**Setup:**

1. Create an iOS SwiftUI app
2. Add files as follows
3. Observe the problem

**AppleApp.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct AppleApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isLocked = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Unlocked view")
                .padding()
        }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isLocked) {

        } content: {
            LockScreen($isLocked)
        }


    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**LockScreen.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct LockScreen: View {
    @Binding var isLocked: Bool

    init(_ isLocked: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._isLocked = isLocked
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray
            VStack {
                Text("Locked")
                Button("Unlock") {
                    print("unlock button pressed")
                    isLocked = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LockScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var isLocked: Bool = true
    static var previews: some View {
        LockScreen($isLocked)
    }
}
```

**The problem:**

Take a look at the video: after the app launches the "unlocked view" is visible and "LockScreen" appears after a short delay with animation.

**Desired outcome:**

The app shows "LockScreen" just after the launch, but it's possible to dismiss it by pressing the "unlock" button.

[Video of the problem](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8013017/143567561-fe14bbdc-7f9a-4026-a598-7b04e7ca7406.mp4)

[Project file with sample app](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit/files/7608146/Apple.zip)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI remove transition of fullscreen cover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67754774/swiftui-remove-transition-of-fullscreen-cover)

Comment: Not at all, as it just delays the time where the transition kicks in.

Comment: Just tried your code with my way works fine.```.onAppear() {
            withoutAnimation {
                isLocked = true
            }
        }``` just added this and initially set false for isLocked

Comment: Do you need it to be a FullScreenCover? I have a different approach that maybe you will like more. And it will always show first the white screen until you add a Splash to your project.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/69717515/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi No No No No

Comment: Why this question is closed? "This question needs to be more focused. " - can't get any more focused than this in the SwiftUI land

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment on the @AlexanderThoren answere. I added down animation and also simplify the code.

Add a transition animation.

Add this extension to hide - show view.

```
extension View {
    func showLockView(isLocked: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            self
            if isLocked.wrappedValue {
                LockScreen(isLocked: isLocked).animation(.default).transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom))
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

And use it with your content view

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isLocked = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Unlocked view")
                .padding()
        }
        .showLockView(isLocked: $isLocked) // << Here
    }
}
```

**Edit** : As mentioned in the comment, here is the solution without View extension.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isLocked = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Unlocked view")
                    .padding()
            }
            if isLocked {
                LockScreen(isLocked: $isLocked)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .animation(.default)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please rewrite your code so that there would be no extension? Thanks.

Comment: well better to use an extension or you can check my code before edited. Just got the edited history.

Comment: Just edit it back :) Or publish two solution, your first version is equally as interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hope you find this useful. I know it doesn't have a FullScreenCover, but this will show it instantly.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isLocked = true
    
    var body: some View {
        if self.isLocked {
            LockScreen(isLocked: self.$isLocked)
        } else {
            VStack {
                Text("Unlocked view")
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LockScreen: View {
    @Binding var isLocked: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray
            VStack {
                Text("Locked")
                Button("Unlock") {
                    print("unlock button pressed")
                    isLocked = false
                }
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I've finished with a similar solution. This is as good as it could be, except there is no "slide down" animation when unlocking which I'd like to have.